# String to Float64: multiple-value strconv.ParseFloat() in single-value context

Tags: arrays, go, slice, parsefloat, strconv

I have an array of STRING slices like this:

```
[[header1 header2 startdate enddate header3 header4] 
[item1 100 01/01/2017 02/01/2017 5343340.56343 3.77252223956] 
[item2 554 01/01/2017 02/01/2017 22139.461201388 17.232284405]]
```

Keep in mind that the array keeps on increasing. I am just posting a sample array.

Now I converted some of the float numbers to string so that I could append it to the string slices. However, I need to do some math with those numbers. I want to add the string number(5343340.56343) from the 2nd slice to 3rd string number (22139.461201388). Same thing with the other 2 float numbers in each slices. To do that, I need to first convert them to float64. After getting the sum, I will need to convert them back to string so I can append it to my slice which I will figure out how to do.

To convert the string item to float64, here's what I have:

```
for _, i := range data[1:] {
    if i[0] == "item1" {
        j := strconv.ParseFloat(i[4], 64)


    }
    if i[0] == "item2" {
        k := strconv.ParseFloat(i[4], 64)
    }
    sum := j + k
}
```

This gives an error: multiple-value strconv.ParseFloat() in single-value context
So my question is:

1. How can I convert the string value to Float64.
2. Optional: Any suggestions on how I can add the 2 float numbers from each slice?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the function `ParseFloat` returns two arguments and you are ignoring the second.

```
j, err := strconv.ParseFloat(i[4], 64)
if err != nil {
  // insert error handling here
}
(...)
```

Try to always check the function's signature in [godocs](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat) before using it.

Comment: Thank you, godocs seems to have all the answers. I was spending time looking for solutions in stackoverflow.